# Need a cumulative field in a table

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Database: Sybase ASE 15.0.3

Tables:

```
authors(int author_id, varchar(20) author_name)
books(int author_id,int number_of_pages)
```

I need to add a new field to the table "authors" for total_number_of_pages (the sum of the number of pages for all the books written by the author).

Can this be done by a (possibly materialized) computed field?

I don't like the idea of a view, I really would prefer the field to be in the table authors, if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How many books are in your table?

Comment: What do you want to do when a new edition of a book is entered into the DB?

Comment: @wildplasser: when rows in books are inserted, deleted, updated I want the total to be updated

Comment: @Mark Bannister:
Books are typically 5-20 per author.

Comment: @carlo.borreo: I didn't ask how many books there typically were **per author**, I asked how many books are in your table - **in total**. The reason I ask is because your desired total_number_of_pages represents a form of denormalisation - normally this sort of thing would only be done for very large tables where the total is frequently accessed; the scenario as described does not seem to fit.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: I agree, it is denormalized and ugly. I am sacrificing this to speed. Or at least, I want to see if the gain is worth the sacrifice.
Authors are 200,000 (but only 40,000 have books), books 150,000.
Yes, the total is frequently accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the proper index (on `author_id`) the View solution should actually be quite quick.  It's just a simple aggregation.  Unless you have hundreds or thousands of books per author, this shouldn't be a problem at all.  (I expect the average number of books per author to be under or around 10?)

If you *really* do need to optimise this and store a cached value, I'd recommend a trigger.

As books are added, deleted or updated, in the books table, you alter the value in the authors table appropriately.  It means the least amount of recalculation possible.

The downside of this is increased complexity and interdependence within your design.

Comment: Yes, I do, I really want a field in authors. At least, it should look like this when someone queries it.
The trigger seems the best solution, but it would be even better if I could obtain this result without touching (with a trigger) the definition of books.